# Handle mutitple forms in django template for loop

Tags: python, jquery, django

I am facing problems handling forms in django template for loop using jquery

```
{% for comment in commets %}

<!-- reply to comment -->
<form id="replyform" action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="comment-id" value="{{comment.id}}">

<textarea id="text"> </textarea>
</form>


{% endfor %}


<script>
 $("#replyform").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  var gettext= $("#text",this).val();

 })
</script>
```

Since the form is in a for loop, it there for means more than one form  is created, depending on the number of comments present.

The problem arises when  i click the submit button, my jquery  submit function is not working , but works only for the first form created in the for loop. How can i go about making all the forms created work with jquery submit.

Answer (score 0):

Because You have used here id inside the forloop. Since the form is between forloop then you should set dynamic id for every form element or you can use class.

Comment: how can set dynamic id please help

Answer (score 0):

`id` attribute should be unique

if all of your form will have same submit function,
try to use class instead of id.
`<form class="replyform" ...>` and `<textarea class="text"> </textarea>`

then in your jquery use

```
$('.replyform').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var gettext= $(".text", this).val();
});
```